# Dart: Why is a new instance of an object not a separate object

Tags: object, dart, instance

In Dart, when I create a new instance of an object, it seems that it is in fact the original object and not a new, separate copy. Consider this code:

```
class Bar{
  String name;
  Bar(this.name);
}

class Foo{
  String name;
  List<Bar>bars;
  
  Foo({required this.name, required this.bars});
}

extension ExtendFoo on Foo{
  void addBar(String barName){
    this.bars.add(Bar(barName));
  }
}

class Manage{
  final List<Foo> _fooList =
     [
      Foo(name : 'foo1', bars: [Bar('bar1'),Bar('bar2')]),
      Foo(name : 'foo2', bars: [Bar('bar21'),Bar('bar22')]),
      Foo(name : 'foo3', bars: [Bar('bar31'),Bar('bar32')]),
    ];
    
  List<Foo> get fooList => _fooList;
  
  Foo getFoo(String fooName){
    return _fooList.firstWhere((foo)=> foo.name == fooName);
  }
}
  
  
  
void main() {  
  
  Manage manage = Manage();
  
  Foo editFoo = manage.getFoo('foo2');

  editFoo.addBar('newBar');
  editFoo.name = 'newName';
        
}
```

The objects editFoo and manage[1] are 100% equal at the end of this. In other words: when I updated editFoo I was also updating manage[1].

I actually want a copy of manage[1] that I can manipulate and update without also updating manage[1]. Then later I may decide to replace manage[1] with the copy, but I want control over if and when that happens.

Comment: By `manage[1]`, do you mean `manage.fooList[1]`?  Exactly where do you think you're creating a new instance of a `Foo` object?  In the code you've shown, `Foo` objects are constructed only when initializing `manage._fooList`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `return _fooList.firstWhere((foo)=> foo.name == fooName);`  is not creating a new object of `Foo`. It is passing the `Foo` instance by reference.

Take a look at this

```
class Bar {
  String name;

  Bar(this.name);
}

class Foo {
  String name;
  List<Bar> bars;

  Foo({required this.name, required this.bars});
}

extension ExtendFoo on Foo {
  void addBar(String barName) {
    this.bars.add(Bar(barName));
  }
}

class Manage {
  final List<Foo> _fooList = [
    Foo(name: 'foo1', bars: [Bar('bar1'), Bar('bar2')]),
    Foo(name: 'foo2', bars: [Bar('bar21'), Bar('bar22')]),
    Foo(name: 'foo3', bars: [Bar('bar31'), Bar('bar32')]),
  ];

  List<Foo> get fooList => _fooList;

  Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
    int i = _fooList.indexWhere((foo) => foo.name == fooName);
    if (i == -1) {
      return null;
    }
    Foo foo = _fooList[i];
  Foo? getFoo(String fooName) {
    int i = _fooList.indexWhere((foo) => foo.name == fooName);
    if (i == -1) {
      return null;
    }
    Foo foo = _fooList[i];
    return Foo(name: foo.name, bars: List.generate(foo.bars.length, (i) => foo.bars[i]));
  }  }
}

void main() {
  Manage manage = Manage();

  Foo editFoo = manage.getFoo('foo2');

  editFoo.addBar('newBar');
  editFoo.name = 'newName';

  print(editFoo.name); //newName
  print(manage.fooList[1].name); //foo2
  print(manage.fooList[1] == editFoo); //false
}
```

If you have null safety on use this:

```
  Foo? getFoo(String fooName) {
    int i = _fooList.indexWhere((foo) => foo.name == fooName);
    if (i == -1) {
      return null;
    }
    Foo foo = _fooList[i];
    return Foo(name: foo.name, bars: List.generate(foo.bars.length, (i) => foo.bars[i]));
  }
```

And this:

```
Foo editFoo = manage.getFoo('foo2')!;
```

Comment: Not quite - in your example, manage.fooList[1] also had a newBar added. Check manage.fooList[1].bars.last.name. The bars component of editFoo is still coming through as a reference from the fooList instance.

Comment: Oh Oh.I see. I've made changes, check the getFoo now. @Chirs Laurie

Comment: That works. But I think it's messy. I'm a bit disappointed that there isn't an elegant way of getting a full new instance as a copy of an existing object (no embedded references). In my actual code, foo contains several lists of other objects, which in turn can contain lists as well.

Comment: There is a reason it's not possible to get a *clone* of an existing object easily: It would bypass the constructor. Dart objects should generally only be created by calling their constructors, since the constructors may uphold some meaningful invariants for the class (like no two different objects having the same `id`). If you can just clone an object, you break such invariants, so you can't. If you want to create a new instance, you must call a constructor somewhere.